# Reminder software for regular chores around the house

Tags: linux

I'm looking for reminder software for regular chores around the house.

Perhaps even to put on a permanent tablet mounted on the wall in the house; although it would be great if it could be edited and modified remotely (and securely).

I remember seeing an (android) app on a friends phone ~15 years ago that reminded him to do things (cut nails, get hair cut, change bedsheets).  What I loved about it was you gave each item a "re-occurrence" and when you clicked "done" it would push items to the bottom of the list where they would slowly bubble up to the top again.

The beauty of this is that jobs's don't need to be done on a fixed day (it's not a calendar).  I'm currently using my Calendar but if I'm on holiday the week that I'm supposed to be "cleaning the shower" then I forget all about it or do it a week later and then do it again too soon when it next comes round.

There are also two of us so, hence the idea of a home dashboard where the two of us look at the list each evening and just do a task that needs doing instead of constantly having to ask when we last did thing or if that calendar entry is right

I am a home-labber and use Linux over Windows. Nothing Windows or Mac will work for me. I am very happy to self host but also happy to use a cloud product.

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: *I'm looking for reminder software for regular chores around the house.*  Isn't that called a ***spouse***? :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend: Todoist. I use this across my windows, linux and mac environments and it is also on my Apple Phone, JIRA Integration and Confluence as well for work...it all seemlessly integrates together and syncs via cloud.

You can setup reoccuring daily, weekly, monthly tasks that need to get done at a set time...I use this heavily for work and home life to keep track of paying bills, etc.

It can be setup for free, or if you need more advanced features then it's $4/mo.

**General Info:** https://todoist.com/

**Integrations:** https://todoist.com/integrations

**Linux:** https://todoist.com/help/articles/how-to-install-todoist-on-linux#install-todoist-using-appimage

Answer (score 2):

I use [TickTick](https://www.ticktick.com/) for this.

It will synchronize your reminders across pretty much every platform going.  I use it on Windows, Ubuntu, Android and Mac.  Entering a task on one will provide reminders on all.

You can send emails to it and have them create new reminders.

Reminders can be one-shot or recurring.  Recurring ones can be on a number of different criteria.  Once a recurring reminder is marked 'done', it goes to the end of the list as you require.

It is free and has no advertising.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using Tasks management sofware, you should also check out [Grocy](https://grocy.info/) even though it can do more household stuff than you may need:

- It is web-based and self-hosted.
- It has many plugins.
- You can track chores via tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Asana, free version for this. It is available for Android, Windows and iOs. But not for linux. So you can use it from your phone.

I have a mixture of date based and undated task entries. While it wont bubble, you can drag the one done, down the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash shell script for exactly this problem. It isn't fancy. It has no user interface other than the shell prompt. It doesn't do any formatting. Just spits out a list, one item per line.

The chore list is a flat text file with sub-lists with headers like "Daily:", "Tuesday:", "LastMondayofMay:", etc. separated by blank lines, and has two functions that do the bulk of the work: getSection() and selectChore() for grabbing entire sections and for getting one chore from a section.

If you know bash or Python you could probably write something similar, or better that what I use. And if you use Python you could easily port it to other systems (Windows).

Comment: Unless you supply the script, this is not an answer.